# see Batman in the theatre

Tags: articles

> I’m going to see Batman in **the** theatre.

In the case that I’m going to see a specific movie, e.g. Batman, do I use definite or indefinite article in locative adjunct? (It’s not yet decided which theatre I would go to.)

Comment: I can't explain why, so I won't make this an answer, but for whatever reason we often use the definite article with places like "the theater", "the hospital", "the park", even if it's not decided which theater, hospital, or park we're referring to. Using the indefinite article here would sound wrong.

Comment: @ThePhoton Consulting CGEL, both ‘_the_’ and ‘_a_’ can be interpreted either referentially or non-referentially, in the scope of verbs like _want_, which create hypothetical worlds. Other verbs that create such contexts include _be going, intend, desire, ask for, look for, seek, dream_. (p.404) So even ‘a theatre’ can be interpreted referential specific as in: I’m going to see Batman in a theatre (for which my friend already booked.)

Comment: That may be true, but in idiomatic American English, in typical circumstances you would not say "I am going to see Batman in a theater". If I could explain why, I would make an answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton - I agree that the definite article is often used in circumstances like this one. I disagree that the indefinite article would "sound wrong", particularly in certain contexts. For example: "I can't wait until _Guardians of the Galaxy_ comes out on DVD." Answer: "I'm not waiting that long; I want to see it in a theater."

Comment: @J.R., yes but...Q: "Where are you going tonight?" A: "I'm going to see Batman in a theater." (*) At least in my ideolect, this is wrong.

Comment: @ThePhoton - Agreed. See my comment under mohamed's answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton - You really ought to elaborate on your initial comment in an answer. I think your comment is better than the only answer given thus far (an answer that was, unfortunately, accepted way too soon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it's entirely idiomatic, with no particular reason, but when we talk about certain places we commonly use the definite article even when we're discussing an unspecified one out of several places:

> I'm going to **the** theater.

(even if there are several theaters I might be going to)

> Bob was in **the** hospital for three days.
>
> We had fun at **the** park.

In none of these cases would we substitute "a" for "the".

Also note, British English (sometimes?) uses no article at all for the case of "hospital". ("Bob was in hospital for three days").

As J.R. points out, there are also cases where the indefinite or definite article could both be used:

> Q: I can't wait until Guardians of the Galaxy comes out on DVD.
>
> A: I'm not waiting that long; I want to see it in a (the) theater.

Unfortunately I can't tell you what makes this example different from the previous ones.

**Edit**

Thinking about CarSmack's comment, I think when we use "the" with a place we are implying that we were there to do whatever activity is typical in that place.

> I went to **the** theater [to watch a movie].
>
> Bob was in **the** hospital [to receive medical care].

If we talk about going to these places to do something non-typical, then using the indefinte article sounds more natural

> I went to **a** hospital to repair the air-conditioning.

or

> Q: Where do you work?
>
> A: I work at **a** hospital [doing IT support].

Comment: I find nothing unnatural to AE that Bob was in a hospital for three days, or that we had fun at a park. To me, both these sentences fall under your second category: either definite or indefinite article--sometimes depending on context.

Comment: @CarSmack If you say "Bob was in a hospital for 3 days" it sounds like maybe he got lost and was wandering the halls trying to find the exit. If you say he was in "the hospital" for 3 days it sounds like he was sick or injured and being cared for there.

Comment: Yes, your Edit is about what I was now thinking: “(1) to do whatever activity is (2) typical in that place.” ‘The’, in ‘I’m going to the theater’, seems to denote two ways. It is “referential”, for indicating my going there and my time at the place. At the same time, it is “non-referential” [(to refer to a thing in general)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/the), for it being connected with typical activity that the place renders.

Comment: This view leaves the issue about (1) ‘play soccer’ vs (2) ‘play the violin.’ (2) can be explained by the former sayings. (The fact that ‘soccer’ is activity itself not instrument makes it not use article? It may not that simple, for we would say “she can dance the waltz. : 'Play' is light verb, 'dance' in not makes the difference? Difficult is the learning.) Thank you for giving me a pleasurable time for thinking about this matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you will not see in the house, for example, or in another place and you wanted to clarify that the `place` where you will see the film is "Theatre", then, use "The" as you did.

Otherwise, use "A" because you didn't identify which theatre to watch the film at.

Comment: _use "A" because you didn't identify which theatre to watch the film at_... This is an oft-quoted and oversimplified way to say when to use one article instead of the other. One can say, "We're going to the theater tonight to watch Batman," and the answer might be, "Which theater?"

Comment: Drive-by upvoters: Why do you think this answer is correct?